# How to open a word document file(.doc) in Editable mode in C#/WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, office-interop

When I  run this code it opens file in Readonly  mode but I want to open my document file in Editable mode.I have already readonly mode set to false.This is the code which i have using:-

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application winword = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document document = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();

try
{
    //Set status for word application is to be visible or not.
    //Create a missing variable for missing value
    object readOnly = false;
    object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    object isVisible = true;

    document = winword.Documents.Open(pathToFile, ReadOnly: false, Visible: true);
    document.Activate();

    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(winword);

    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(document);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // WB.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    throw;
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code, and it opened all my sample documents in read-write mode. The only change I had to make is `winword.Visible = true;`. Do you have problems only with certain *.doc files or are **all** *.doc files (even simple ones) opened in read-only mode? Which version of Word are you using?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you can't do it. Readonly mode is provided in part as a security measure to stop some macros from executing in Word. Thus, to provide an SDK overriding it would be a risk to end-users. You might be able to get around it by running the exe directly with a parameter of the filename, since then it would be like a person double-clicking the icon, but I'm not familiar with what libraries are or are not available in WPF. In good ol'-fashioned consoles or Windows Forms, you'd be looking at

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start([the path of Word.exe], pathToFile);
```

but you'd have to be careful about finding the path to Word.exe, since that could vary based on the version of word and what installation instructions were given. It's conceivable that those COM objects will expose the path somehow, since there's a good chance they'd need to know it, but yet again I'm not familiar with them.